# What is considered better style? One big loop or multiple small ones?

Tags: coding-style

I'm currently working with a big container that i need to iterater over an do lots of things. Which of the following is considered better style?

a) Big Loop:

```
for (container::iterator it = myContainer.begin(); it < myContainer.end(); ++it) {
    // do thing a with *it

    // do thing d with *it

    // do thing c with *it

    // do thing b with *it
}
```

b) Small Loops:

```
for (container::iterator it = myContainer.begin(); it < myContainer.end(); ++it) {
    // do thing a with *it
}

for (container::iterator it = myContainer.begin(); it < myContainer.end(); ++it) {
    // do thing b with *it
}

for (container::iterator it = myContainer.begin(); it < myContainer.end(); ++it) {
    // do thing c with *it
}

for (container::iterator it = myContainer.begin(); it < myContainer.end(); ++it) {
    // do thing d with *it
}
```

I find b) better to read since a) will get clunky really easy and harder to understand. But a) will run faster I think. So which of those is better style? myContainer will contain up to 10.000 elements and this procedure will have to be repeated so performance is important.

Comment: are they all bound to the same condition? Also, what language are you working with?

Comment: Have you considered extracting the loop body into a method in the a) option?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: the whole thing is one single function I don't think splitting loop body into a seperate function would help much, since I need to access a few variables outside the loop.

Comment: If performance is important, that trumps the question of "better style." Performance considerations force you to do lots of ugly things. You don't do them unless you have to, but when you do...

Comment: @LukasSchmelzeisen: ok I get the point. Then go for a single loop (if performance is your target), but extract `myContainer.end()` into a variable and don't use `<` for the iterator comparison, use `==`. (Oh, and don't increment `end`, increment `it` instead :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the single loop. You could refactor the code contained inside the loop into separate functions.

Splitting the big loop into four smaller loops is rather inefficient, it adds superfluous operations.

Comment: This answer does not explain any "why"s. The amount of byte-code added is insignificant and it's rather unclear which implementation might run faster(one big loop or multiple smaller loops).

Answer (score 7):

There are further refactoring benefits to splitting your separate tasks to different loops.

Loop performance isn't always very straight-forward when handling big data sets so you should usually start with readability and go back to single loop if needed.

Here's [Split Loop refactoring example](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/splitLoop.html) by Martin Fowler.

> You often see loops that are doing two different things at once, because
> they can do that with one pass through a loop. Indeed most programmers
> would feel very uncomfortable with this refactoring as it forces you to
> execute the loop twice - which is double the work.
>
> But like so many optimizations, doing two different things in one loop
> is less clear than doing them separately. It also causes problems for
> further refactoring as it introduces temps that get in the way of
> further refactorings. So while refactoring, don't be afraid to get rid
> of the loop. When you optimize, if the loop is slow that will show up
> and it would be right to slam the loops back together at that point. You
> may be surprised at how often the loop isn't a bottleneck, or how the
> later refactorings open up another, more powerful, optimization.

#### Original code

```
void printValues() {
  double averageAge = 0;
  double totalSalary = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    averageAge += people[i].age;
    totalSalary += people[i].salary;
  }
  averageAge = averageAge / people.length;
  System.out.println(averageAge);
  System.out.println(totalSalary);
}
```

#### Becomes initially

```
void printValues() {
  double totalSalary = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    totalSalary += people[i].salary;
  }

  double averageAge = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    averageAge += people[i].age;
  }
  averageAge = averageAge / people.length;

  System.out.println(averageAge);
  System.out.println(totalSalary);
}
```

#### Cleaned code after extracting methods

```
void printValues() {
  System.out.println(averageAge());
  System.out.println(totalSalary());
}

private double averageAge() {
  double result = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    result += people[i].age;
  }
  return result / people.length;
}

private double totalSalary() {
  double result = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    result += people[i].salary;
  }
  return result;
}
```